# Malformed jQuery Mobile dialog in web app on mobile screens

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[image]

---

I have a webapp in which the dialog box which appears on a specific page however it gets malformed for some reason. Please see link below for example

It seems to be because of these lines of code which shows the loading animation.

JS:

```
//show loading screen before pagehide
$(document).on('pagebeforehide', '[data-role="page"]',function(e,data){  
 var loader = setInterval(function(){
  $.mobile.loading('show');
  clearInterval(loader);
 },1); 
}); 

//hide loading screen on pageshow
$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]',function(e,data){  
 var loader = setInterval(function(){
  $.mobile.loading('hide');
  clearInterval(loader);
 },1); 
});  

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="dialog"]',function(e,data){  
 var loader = setInterval(function(){
  $.mobile.loading('hide');
  clearInterval(loader);
 },1); 
});
```

When I change

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="dialog"]',function(e,data)
```

to

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="dialog"]',function(e,data)
```

The malformed dialog shows for a moment then returns to normal.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="loginPage" data-close-btn="none">
 <div data-role="header">
 <img src="./images/Chune-Logo-white-logo.png" alt="logo" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;"></div>

 <div data-role="content">    
  <form id="loginForm">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
   <label for="username">Username:</label>
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username" />
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
   <label for="password">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" /></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submitButton">
  </form>
  <div style="text-align: center;">Or</div> <!--need to center-->
  <a href="./register.html" data-role="button">Register</a>
 </div>
 <div data-role="footer">
  <h4>&copy; CHUNE</h4>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I stop this dialog and others from becoming malformed on small screen devices as it shows normal on desktops and laptops.

Comment: the link shows XML code only.

Comment: added the image itself its a bit large though